# Legacy API requires to pass callback name as string. Can I improve that API via an extension method?

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm faced with a legacy API that doesn't use .NET events, but rather requires me to do this:

```
// (first arg is System.Object, second arg is string, myFoo is of type Foo)
myFoo.AddCallback(this, "DoSomething(int)");
```

This API requires that `DoSomething` be an instance method on `this`, and that it take an int.

Is there a way I can use force this API to be usable in a typesafe way?

*More precisely:* I want to write an extension method for Foo, which allows me to call AddCallback with a .NET delegate, rather than a receiver-signature pair. I'm imagining something like this:

```
// extension method definition
public static void AddCallback(this Foo foo, Action action)
{
    foo.AddCallback(
        FigureOutReceiverOf(action),    // ?
        FigureOutSignatureOf(action));  // ?
}

public static void AddCallback<T>(this Foo foo, Action<T> action)
{ ... } // and so on, for up to, say, 10 type-arguments

// usage:
myFoo.AddCallback(DoSomething)
// or even a lambda:
myFoo.AddCallback((i) => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

If it's possible to do this via an extension method hack, it would make my life better. Also I'm simply interested if it's possible given C#'s capabilities.

By the way, the legacy API is called qt4dotnet.

Comment: What must the signature of the callback be? Always `void Method(int)`?

Comment: no, it can return anything, and it can take any args. However, the return type should not be included in the "signature" string. And if the callback returns non-void, the value it returns is ignored by Foo.

Comment: But what arguments will the API pass to the method if it takes 'any args'? Isn't the signature specific to the particular `AddCallBackXX` method on the API?

Comment: No. As I said, Foo.AddCallback is not typesafe. So you can pass a method with any signature. Then, later, Foo will use reflection to invoke the callback, which will fail at runtime if a mismatching signature was passed to AddCallback.

Comment: The required signature is not always `void Method(int)`. It varies between different instances of Foo. Think of Foo as a non-generic "event" type. You may have a "Foo mouseClicked" that requires your callback sig to be "Method(Point)". And you may have a "Foo selectionChanged" that requires your callback sig to be "Method(ListWidgetItem)". Both of those are of type Foo.

Comment: Ok, got it. I think it's weird that the API would force you to pass `"DoSomething(int)"` rather than just `"DoSomething"` when, in context, the callback is *expected* to be of a certain signature.

Comment: Agreed, it's weird. There's probably some justification (maybe avoiding possible overload-ambiguities), but whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a lambda would be tricky - it will end up being a method in a different class, if it captures local variables. You could detect that, of course, but it wouldn't be compile-time safe.

Likewise the signature part is interesting, in that if it's *definitely* an `Action`, the delegate has no parameters. You can't just make the parameter `Delegate`, or method group conversions won't work... although you could still call

```
myFoo.AddCallBack(new Action<int>(MyMethodName));
```

An alternative is to produce a bunch of overloads:

```
public static void AddCallback(this Foo foo, Action action)

public static void AddCallback<T>(this Foo foo, Action<T> action)

public static void AddCallback<T1, T2>(this Foo foo, Action<T1, T2> action)
```

It wouldn't be elegant, but you'd probably only need a few for practical reasons. If any methods returned values, you'd need similar ones for `Func`.

There's the additional potential problem of passing a delegate with multiple actions... again, you could check this at compile-time. Finally, you might want to check that the `Target` of the delegate is the same as the `foo` parameter.

With these problems out of the way, working out the signature is *relatively* straightforward. You use the `Delegate.Method` property, and from that you can get the name and parameter types. If the library requires `"int"` rather than `"System.Int32"` etc then you'll need a bit of faffing around that, but it shouldn't be too bad. (It does sound like a pretty odd API though.)

Comment: Yes, a bunch of overloads (with varying arg counts) was exactly what I was envisioning. It's a small price to pay. The main question is, how to implement "FigureOutReceiverOf", considering there isn't always a real receiver (in the case of lambdas or static methods). (also, maybe FigureOutReceiverOf is unnecessary and I should be using some other trick)

Comment: Ok, I got it - the "FigureOutReceiverOf" thing I wanted is actually Action.Target. Thanks Jon, your solution works with instance methods. Now I'll try making it work with static methods and lambdas too. To do that, I'll detect when such things are passed to me, and I'll wrap them in wrapper objects, so I have something to pass as the "receiver" param.

Comment: Ok, I switched to a simpler design. As the "receiver", I use the Action<...> itself. And as the signature, I use Action's Invoke method, with the parameter-list generated as you described. Works like a charm.